# Can I split multiple columns but leave some cells merged?

Tags: excel

I have a csv file with loads of data. It looks like the below screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrdGE.png).

Basically what I need is to split 2 columns into rows with power query (reference 1 and Delivery).
Reference 1 is always separated by space and Delivery data is always separated by line feed.
So it would look like the below screenshot, so each reference is matched up to its delivery.
However I need the miles and the price NOT to be duplicated as this would give us wrong total numbers, so I need those merged. (There's also a Job no column in case this would help - this would indicate if 2 or 3 deliveries were done together.
This is how I would need it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NKRQ.png)

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried splitting the columns separately but then it duplicates data and I would still need to manually delete the extra rows.

| Job No. | Date | Reference 1 | Delivery | Miles | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTM1607 | 03/05/2023 08:00 | GAINSB | Gainsborough Bathrooms Ltd, Walsall, WS9 8SR | 33 | 95 |
| BTM1611 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569189 570075 | Mr Owen, Stockport, SK12 1HHMr Michael Hobbs, Bury, BL9 9RE | 128 | 192 |
| BTM1612 | 02/05/2023 07:00 | 570078 569890 | Mrs Gillian Bunce, Sutton Coldfield, B75 6AGMr Richard Scott, Sutton Coldfield, B74 2AL | 35 | 52.5 |
| BTM1613 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 418719 570246 | D Jiggens, Twickenham, TW2 6PUMrs J Smith, Surbiton, KT6 6QP | 125 | 187.5 |
| BTM1614 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569539 570036 | Mr Charles Docherty, London, SE4 2DXMrs Anne Kirby, Dagenham, RM8 2PU | 136 | 204 |
| BTM1615 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569435 570025 | Mr Brian Harrison, Stoke-on-Trent, ST1 2ARMrs Shirley Steiert, Ellesmere Port, CH65 6RA | 118 | 177 |
| BTM1616 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569249 569172 | Mrs Jill Gardham, Bath, BA2 6PLMr Roy Foster, Shaftesbury, SP7 0PJ | 134 | 201 |
| BTM1617 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569903 569287 | Mrs Hill, Bristol, BS15 9UJMrs A Devlin, Cardiff, CF14 1EH | 132 | 198 |

I need it in the below format (but with the duplicated miles&price merged into 1), but I can't find a solution anywhere.

| Job No. | Date | Reference 1 | Delivery | Miles | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BTM1607 | 03/05/2023 08:00 | GAINSB | Gainsborough Bathrooms Ltd, Walsall, WS9 8SR | 33 | 95 |
| BTM1611 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569189 | Mr¬†Owen, Stockport, SK12 1HH | 128 | 192 |
| BTM1611 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 570075 | Mr Michael Hobbs, Bury, BL9 9RE | 128 | 192 |
| BTM1612 | 02/05/2023 07:00 | 570078 | Mrs Gillian Bunce, Sutton Coldfield, B75 6AG | 35 | 52.5 |
| BTM1612 | 02/05/2023 07:00 | 569890 | Mr Richard Scott, Sutton Coldfield, B74 2AL | 35 | 52.5 |
| BTM1613 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 418719 | D Jiggens, Twickenham, TW2 6PU | 125 | 187.5 |
| BTM1613 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 570246 | Mrs J Smith, Surbiton, KT6 6QP | 125 | 187.5 |
| BTM1614 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 569539 | Mr Charles Docherty, London, SE4 2DX | 136 | 204 |
| BTM1614 | 02/05/2023 06:00 | 570036 | Mrs Anne Kirby, Dagenham, RM8 2PU | 136 | 204 |

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried.  Also, edit your question to post your data as text which can be copy/pasted easily, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Power Query, it is not possible to produce "Merged Cells". The code below only writes the miles and price amounts into the first row of the entries for a particular Job No. You would then have to merge the cells manually or by using a VBA routine.

There are other options, but if you must have merged cells, you will need to develop a VBA solution for that.

Paste the code below into the Advanced Editor, changing the second line to reflect your actual Table Name in your workbook.

Read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm. The new table is created by applying the `Tables.FromColumns` method to each subgroup of Job No.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Job No.", type text}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"Reference 1", type text}, 
        {"Delivery", type text}, {"Miles", Int64.Type}, {"Price", type number}},"en-GB"),

//Group by Job number
//then split into rows
//Price and miles only on first row
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Job No."}, {
        {"New Table", (t)=>Table.FromColumns(
                {t[#"Job No."]}
                 & {t[Date]}
                 & {Text.Split(t[Reference 1]{0}," ")}
                 & {Text.Split(t[Delivery]{0},"#(lf)")}
                 & {t[Miles]}
                 & {t[Price]},
            Table.ColumnNames(t)),
            type table [#"Job No."=nullable text, Date=nullable datetime, Reference 1=nullable text, Delivery=nullable text, Miles=nullable number, Price=nullable number]   
            }}),

//Expand the grouped tables exceot for Job No.
    #"Expanded New Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "New Table", 
        {"Date", "Reference 1", "Delivery", "Miles", "Price"}),

//Fill down the date column
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Expanded New Table",{"Date"})
in
    #"Filled Down"
```

***Your Original Data***
[image]

***Results from Above***
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!! this worked exactly as expected!!! thanks